# finding how many consecutive numbers in an array [java]

Tags: java

For example, array is like this  {1,1,2,1,1,1 } and they key int is 1, the Largest number of consecutive times 1 is going to be 3.  When i run my code and type the same numbers, I'm getting 4 consecutive numbers of 1. Can someone give me advice? is there a built-in method that will help me solve this?

```
 Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
            int count = 1;
            int largest = 0;

            System.out.println("Enter number");
            int numbers = kbd.nextInt();
            int[] numb = new int[numbers];
            System.out.println("Now enter "+numbers+" integers:");
            for(int i =0; i<numb.length;i++){
                numb[i] = kbd.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Now enter the key integer: ");
            int key = kbd.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i<numb.length-1; i++) {
            if (numb[i] == key) {
                if (numb[i] == numb[i + 1]) {
                     count++;
                    }
            else {
                    largest = Math.max(largest, count);
                    count = 1;

                  }
           }
    }

            System.out.println("Largest number of consecutive times "+key+" was entered: "+largest);
```

Comment: I think your code will always return 1 for any number. which is also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach.

```
count = 0;
for (int i : numb){
  if (i == key){
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
  if(largest<count) {
    largest = count;
  }
}
```

Comment: i like it, this one is much easier to follow. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you should have a second inner loop, it should just be

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1<numb.length; i++){
   if(numb[i] == numb[i + 1]){
      count++;
   }else{
      if(largest<count) {
        largest = count;
        count = 1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you pls check the code again? count is off by 1

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign `count` to `0` in the if condition (In your initial code before editing).

```
if(largest<count){
   largest = Math.max(largest, count);
   count = 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/x4GhCM)

And in the current code just add a if condition checking whether largest is greater than count after the for loop.

`largest = (largest > count) ? largest : count;`

Or

```
if (count > largest){
   largest = count;
}
```

Comment: thanks for providing the code! your code works mine still not but I'll figure it out

Comment: @john Did you reassigned `count` to `0` in the if condition of your initial code (I mean the code before editing the question).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
        int numb[] = new int[] { 6, 3, 3, 5,5,5 ,3, 5, 15,15 };
        int key = 3; // Can be changed
        int largest = 0;
        int currCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
            if (numb[i] == key) {
                currCount++;
            } else {
                if (currCount > largest) {
                    largest = currCount;
                }
                currCount = 0;
            }
        }
        if (currCount > largest) {
            largest = currCount;
        }

        System.out.println("Largest number of consecutive times " + key + " was entered: " + largest);
```

Comment: Why do you set key to 15?

Comment: And when you pass through a number different from the key, you have to reset count. This one counts all the keys- consecutive & non-consecutive .

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i<numb.length; i++) {
    if (numb[i] == key) {
        if(i == numb.length-1){
            count =1;
        }
        else if (numb[i] == numb[i+1]) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count > largest) {
            largest = count;
        }
    }
    else
        count = 1;
}
```

Comment: Down voter would you tell me what to improve. Thanks!

Comment: Can u tell me your output for  key = 3 and input :  { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };

Comment: I also posted the same answer den I removed quickly before someone downvote that. Here most of the answer seems wrong. I have posted again. Please upvote if you find it right.